# Mail issue on XAMPP Localhost

Tags: php, xampp

I am using XAMPP 1.7.4 on Windows 8 When Mail Script is executed I got error ***Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 553 We do not relay non-local mail, sorry*** however this code works very well on live server

So what can be the issue ?
Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: are you checking on localhost?

Comment: yes I am checking on localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error says it all. The SMTP server you're connecting to replies, that it doesn't relay non-local mail. So whatever SMTP server you've configured, it doesn't like it when the sending party is non-local, p.e. `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

It doesn't seem to be an error in your code, it is more likely a configuration error in your script or in the SMTP server you want to relay to.